# Problems by setting up Appium

Tags: ios, node.js, xcode, selenium, appium

I want to set up an Appium test automtion framework on **Mac OS (El Capitan)**.
First, I want to run test automation by **iOS simulator** and the Appium test app **UICatalog**.
Currently I ran into some problems. Also I have to mention that I'm quite new to testing stuff...

What I have installed so far:

- xCode 7.2.1
- Appium GUI
- Node.js
- Java JDK 1.8.0_51

When I run the **Appium Doctor** by GUI there are no problems listed!

Question so far:

- Is the Appium GUI the same as the `npm` installation like this

`npm install -g appium`

`npm install wd`

`appium &`

- Do I still need the selenium package? Or does it come with the Appium GUI?
- When I start Appium server by GUI I receive the following state:
  [image]

Why does it get locked? What is missing?

- Do I have to run xCode besides Appium server when I want to test an app?
- How do I grant Appium access to the iOS simulator? Is this still necessary? I haven't get an authentification like this.

I hope anyone can give me some hints :).

Comment: whats the issue here .. I can see your `Appium` sever is started on port `4723`

Comment: Yes. But what is missing? Do I have to install/run selenium? Do I have to run xCode besides? I always get this screen but I should get further connection details...

Comment: yes now you have to run appium script and all the logs would be printed here.

Comment: Sorry. Don't get it. Can you give me more detailed information? Which appium script?

Comment: @SteveMurdock : post this installation and setup of Appium, all you need to  do is write a block of code to setup the capabilities and driver on the same port as Appium server is listening to.

Answer (score 0):

I see your appium port is running on 4723. When you run your appium test scripts, which has port 4723 mentioned on your script itself. Your automated test cases would automatically run on the 4723.

Appium requires backend server port to be running. This way it communicates with your device.

Comment: Mm. Okay. So I configure Appium GUI like shown above. I start the server. Then I start my test script which connects to 0.0.0.0:4723, right? Do I have to run/start a selenium webdriver, too? Do I have to run xCode beside? Do I have to start the iOS simulator by xCode?

Comment: Yes you got it. Yes, you have to start simulator or connect your device. Mention that device in your scripts. Appium would run that device on your running port i.e 4723. This is just the GUI showing appium server is running on port 4723.

Answer (score 0):

The appium GUI is the Server GUI which shows what all happens in the back end when u trigger your script. All you need to do is , use the same port no in ur script while running,

eg:

```
iosDriver driver=new iosDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done automation using Appium+Cucumber+Java so I had the same questions you had. Here are some answers for you based on my experience-

Appium Gui is not the same as npm. They are 2 separate components. Appium uses node.js framework. So you need to install Appium and node.js (npm) separately. The command you mentioned

```
npm install -g appium
```

would install the Appium server. To install the Appium GUI you need to download and install it from this link - http://appium.io/downloads.html

Follow these instructions where I give step by step instructions on how to set up Appium - http://www.rajsubra.com/2016/04/03/appiumjavacucumber-set-up-step-by-step-instructions/

If you follow the above steps you should be able to run tests via the iOS Simulator.

Also the state you mentioned in the screenshot with the Appium GUI is the normal expectations. It is just saying the Appium server started via the GUI and also gives you details on what simulator configuration has been selected.